# Add javascript vars to data.loadGeoJson

Tags: javascript, web2py, geojson

I use Google maps API with the Web2py framework.

How can I send with map.data.loadGeoJson some javascript vars to the url that must return the geojson data?
Or how can I transform map.data.loadGeoJson in a classical ajax call?

```
var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("events_map"), {
        center: {lat: 45.070309, lng: 7.686580999999933},
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeControl: false
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
        var ne = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
        var north = ne.lat();
        var east = ne.lng();
        var sw = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
        var south = sw.lat();
        var west = sw.long();
        map.data.loadGeoJson('{{=URL('f_ajax', 'get_locations_g')}}', vars to add like east?);
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just append the variables to the URL in the Javascript code:

```
var queryString = '?east=' + east + '&west=' + west;
map.data.loadGeoJson('{{=URL('f_ajax', 'get_locations_g')}}' + queryString);
```

Comment: Really simple. Thank you.